# determining the effect of the change in an independent variable using regression

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm creating a regression model that predicts a customer's spending based on their income, age, gender , and region. The model looks as follows:

```
lm(spending ~ income + age + gender + region, data = tab.ordercustomers)
```

I want to see what the effect of an extra $10,000 go income is on spending. Would I do this by adding 10,000 to each income observation in `tab.ordercustomers` and then create another regression model? If so, how would I then determine the effect of this extra $10,000?

Comment: What is your objective with adding the extra 10k?

Comment: The coefficient for income tells you the effect of each additional 1 dollar on spending. See for example [How to Interpret P-values and Coefficients in Regression Analysis](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/interpret-coefficients-p-values-regression/).

Comment: **tl;dr** `1e4*coef(fitted_model)["income"]`, but you'll get a better answer on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)  (is this homework??)